# How to get the static variable value from the dll

Tags: c++

I need to get the value from the DLL.

### X.exe

```
extern __declspec(dllimport) int fun();

int y = fun();
```

exe cpp is calling dll function and expecting the return value.

### Y.dll

```
static int x = 10;

int fun()
{
 return x;
}
```

dll cpp function is returning the static variable value.

when i am checking value of "y", its always zero.

can you please tell me is it possible to get the value of x in the exe using the fun().

Comment: Did you export `fun()` with `__declspec(dllexport)`?

Comment: you need to post exact code the reproduces the behavior you are experiencing. What you have now works as expected.